# How do I use jQuery to select the next table row with a particular class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table that contains rows with different class names. Some of these rows have the same class names. I am trying to select the next table row (using jQuery) that contains a particular class. Basically, I am attempting to create a feature where a user can select the next row in a table by using the arrow keys. Here is the code I am using:

```
if (e.keyCode == 40)
{ 
   $('tr.background_color_grey').next("tr").addClass("background_color_grey");
   $('tr.background_color_grey:first').removeClass("background_color_grey");
   return false;
}
```

The problem is that I need to skip over some rows (they act as headers for different categories in the table). So, how can I select the next row in the table, provided that it has a particular class? All of the rows that I would like to be selected have the class "can_be_selected". Thanks for any help!

Comment: So are you just trying to use the keyboard to highlight one row, skipping the header rows?

Comment: Yes. I have a table that contains one column. Some of the rows are headers. The highlighting needs to skip these rows. I still can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hYCpJ/)**?

The example has a table with one column and 10 rows. Cells are all `<td>` elements where selected cells have the class `can_be_selected`. By using your up and down arrow keys you can highlight the cells with the class `can_be_selected` only with the other cells being ignored. Note that in the example, I gave the cells that have the class `can_be_selected` a green border to make them distinct, but you can easily remove this.

This is a **[second jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xVEt6/)** using the same code where table rows have been substituted for table cells.

**jQuery** (for the first jsFiddle example):

```
var index = -1;
//38 up, 40down
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        index = (index + 1 >= $('td.can_be_selected').length) ? $('td.can_be_selected').length - 1 : index + 1;
        $('td.can_be_selected').removeClass('background_color_grey');
        $('td.can_be_selected:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('background_color_grey');
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        index = (index == 0) ? 0 : index - 1;
        $('td.can_be_selected').removeClass('background_color_grey');
        $('td.can_be_selected:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('background_color_grey');
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This code is for a basic search feature. If I do a search and arrow down to, say, the 2nd row, then click outside of the search area, the results disappear (as I have intended). So far, so good. However, when I go back to do another search, and then press the down arrow, it highlights the 3rd row, as if it had remembered the previous search where I arrowed down to the 2nd row. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you'd just need to add some code to the code you have that  blanks the results when clicking outside the table so that it resets the index variable to -1 in my example.

Answer (score 3):

in your use of `.next("tr")`

try `.next("tr.can_be_selected")`

Comment: I would not disagree, just answering his core question not optimizing the code.

Comment: next("tr.can_be_selected") did not work? If not please post your HTML as it works like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method to skip all 'useless' rows:

```
$("tr").eq($("tr.selected").nextUntil(".can_be_selected​​​​​​​​​​​").next().index());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/y8Dqq/